# What is the precise definition of a "probability distribution"?

Tags: probability, terminology

I have the impression that the term "distribution" is thrown around carelessly and sometimes incorrectly when non-mathematicians discuss probability.

What is the precise definition of a "probability distribution"?  Is there a universally agreed upon definition?  If there is no completely standard definition, then what are all of the various definitions in use for this term?

Additionally: what are the most common ways in which the word "distribution" is **misused** in discussions of probability?

Comment: It's basically any function whose integral is one.

Comment: Can't be 'any function' - must be non-negative.

Comment: Any measureable function, to say it's integral is one is to imply it's a measurable function to begin with.

Comment: "What is the precise definition of a "probability distribution"?" Any measure with total mass 1. (Note that tons of probability distributions have no densities hence mentioning functions in this context is too restrictive.)

Comment: But, if you want to weight some points, you have to add to the "classical part" a "distributional part" $\sum a_k \delta(.-s_k)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Excellent point. The situation is even worse (or, better...) since any probability distribution has *three* parts: an absolutely continuous part (described by a density), a discrete part (described by some Dirac masses), *and a singular part* (anything not like the above, for example, the uniform distribution on a Cantor set).

Comment: Since this comes up regularly on the site, one might want to go a little further concerning the singular parts and ask what these measures look like. The answer is: they can be any measure $\mu$ (with total mass at most $1$) such that $\mu(\mathbb R\setminus A)=0$ for some measurable $A$ such that Leb$(A)=0$ (this is what "no density part" means) and such that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for every $x$ (thus, no Dirac part) and... and this is basically all one can say! So, as you see, there are some mysterious beasts over there... :-)

Comment: A measure with total mass 1 is in my vocabulary a "probability measure". I speak of a "probability distribution" if the measurable space involved is $\langle\mathbb R^n,\mathcal B\rangle$ where $\mathbb R^n$ is equipped with its usual topology and $\mathcal B$ stands for the connected Borel-$\sigma$-algebra. This is quite subjective though, and I have no justification for it. So I don't exclude that this is a form of misuse of the term.

Comment: @Did Thanks.  So just to be clear: the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = (1/\sqrt{2 \pi}) e^{-\frac12 x^2}$ is *not* a probability distribution, because it is not even a measure.

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid It is at most a "probability distribution function" (PDF) with respect to the Lebesgue-measure.

Comment: What @drhab said in their last comment, minus "at most".

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690289/what-is-a-probability-distribution/1690304

Comment: Unfortunately it is also "thrown around carelessly and sometimes incorrectly" when *mathematicians* dicuss probability. Btw, I am one of them.

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid can you give us a few examples of such misuses of "distribution"?

Comment: @drhab You mean "probability density function", right, which is what PDF stands for.

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid Yes, that is what I mean. Another example of careless use of the term "distribution" :-).

Answer (score 1):

A "probability measure" on a measurable space $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ is a measure $P$ such that $P(\Omega) = 1$.

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ be a probability space and let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be a random variable.  $X$ induces a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ defined by $\mu(E) = P(X \in E)$, where "$X \in E$" denotes the event $\{x \in \Omega \mid X(x) \in E \} = X^{-1}(E)$.  This probability measure $\mu$ is called the "distribution" for $X$, or the "probability distribution" for $X$.

The concept of a "probability measure" is a distinct concept from "the probability distribution for a random variable".  I think that we should not define a probability distribution to be "a measure with total mass $1$", as suggested in the comments, as this seems to blur the two concepts.

Comment: One may add that the function $F_X: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, x\mapsto P(X^{-1}((-\infty, x])) = P(X\leq x)$ is called the *distribution function* of the random variable $X$.